# How to detect orientation using lucas kenade optical flow

Tags: opencv, tracking, feature-detection

I am using OpenCV's `goodFeaturesToTrack` to detect feature and `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` to track them, but calcOpticalFlowPyrLK does not give me orientations of the object.

Is there any other tool to get orientation of the object in OpenCV.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you mean by the 'orientation' of the object?
The question isn't very clear. The LK algorithm will give you vectors pointing in the direction of the motion of your object from which you can derive the orientation.

What is the exact problem you're facing? Are you unable to get an output from the calcOpticalFlowPyrLK function?

Comment: Presently, I am tracking a selected rectangular area on the video feed using calcOpticalFlowPyrLK after taking out features in that area using goodFeaturesToTrack. Presently I'm getting translations of the selected area. I also want to know the orientation change of that rectangular area.